# Distance of pixels from Depth Map - Stereo Vision

Tags: python, numpy, computer-vision, distance

I currently have a Stereo camera that I made using the Jetson nano. I can create a Disparity map with it. However, I want to be able to determine the distance of each pixel from the camera, which I am assuming is possible since I already have a rectified and calibrated stereo pair.

Does anyone know how to do this? The disparity image that is eventually returned and displayed on the screen is a numpy.ndarray class.

Comment: What model did you use to generate the depth map?

Comment: You may want to check this answer: [StackOverFlow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52182331/how-to-find-the-real-depth-distance-from-the-camera-to-the-object-in-m-from-di)